# Why is this specific text being underlined on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have some text where the inline styling is as follows:

```
<a style="margin-left:87px;color:white;">3mm</a>
```

For some reason, it's being underlined **on hover**. It looks like this:

[image: The line is only there when the cursor hovers over the text]

The containing div is:

```
<div class="next-slide-container">
     Poke &nbsp;&nbsp; ID<br>
     Choose your Pokemon<br>
     Details<br>
     Size<br>
</div>
<div class="next-slide-container" style="margin-top:-7px">
     <a style="margin-left:87px;color:white;">3mm</a>
     <img class="texture-icon" role="button" src="Resources/Cutups/Texture_Icons/Pikachu.png">
</div>
```

I tried recreating it with a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1t6dtaL/) but I *cannot* get the text to underline is JSFiddle, even though the css for the container is not different than my own source code. Additionally, the text inside the first div class `next-slide-container`, like "Choose your Pokemon", does not highlight in my code. It's only just "3mm"; so it would seem that the inline styling is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Well it is a link... So what other styles on your page has underlined for links?

Comment: Oh... the <a> tag makes it a link? I thought it was simply "attribute"?

Comment: @epascarello: Scott answered it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, most browsers set anchor tags `<a>` to have the css `text-decoration: underline;` If you want to remove any browser default underlining you need to add `text-decoration: none;` the the css for anchor tags.

Basically... add this to your CSS file or area.

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Some browsers *also* add a default outline or pseudo "glow" to anchor tags (Mozilla).

If you want that to also go away, you would add this to your css for anchor tags:

```
a { text-decoration: none; outline: none; }
```

Valid HTML would mean you need to add either an `href=` value or a `name=` value to the anchor tag. Without one of these, the a tag is invalid.

In your **fiddle**, this invalid anchor tag may be the reason you aren't seeing the same thing as in your browser. Add `href="#"` to the anchor tag in your fiddle and you'll see the same issue. jsFiddle isn't as forgiving with improper markup the way browsers can be. That's kind of the purpose of jsFiddle. Browsers will *guess* at what is meant sometimes, jsFiddle really doesn't.

If you merely want to style the text, you can use `<p>`, `<span>`, `<div>`, `<h1>`, etc. tags. You don't need an anchor tag simply to style text.

Comment: To take the cake, could you suggest an alternative so that way I don't have the change the natural state of the <a> tags? (In case I need to use it later)

Comment: The only other alternative is to not use anchor tags if you don't have href values. TO be honest, I don't know why you're using an anchor there at all.

Comment: So, use <span> or <p>? Sorry, new to HTML.

Comment: Or use a selector that overrides just the links with the "problem" AKA: `.next-slide-container a {}`

Comment: Yes a paragraph tag would work, that's a block level element though. A span would also work and spans are inline elements similar to anchors. Then if you want the pointy hand cursor, you need to add `cursor: pointer;` to the CSS for that element.

Comment: @Scott: "TO be honest, I don't know why you're using an anchor there at all." Because I thought <a> simply was for styling the attributes of something, I didn't realize it was <a> for "anchor" haha. So, since you're hinting that it doesn't make sense to do it, I don't want to "use a selector that overrides just the links with the "problem" AKA" because they don't need to be links. Just specifically styled text, that's it.

Comment: @Scott: "Yes a paragraph tag..." Okay! Thank you!

Comment: Ahhh then yes use p or span :) Or even div would work. :)

Comment: @Scott: Thank you so much. This little problem alone has taught me a lot and you've assisted immensely with that. I'll award you the problem once the timer is up.

Comment: Glad I could help @8protons